# Connecting an Arduino Nano 33 IoT to an Android app through Bluetooth

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, arduino-nano

I am working on connecting an Arduino nano 33 iot to an android app via the Bluetooth capabilities of the iot device. I have seen many resources referring to the use of a Bluetooth module, but no resources about using the nano 33 iot Bluetooth capabilities.

I am wanting to receive data from the Arduino via Bluetooth connection and display it in an android app. I had developed an app that can see the Arduino in a list of Bluetooth devices but am unable to connect to the Arduino due to it not being able to be paired with the phone.

Thanks

Comment: How about using Bluetooth LE? No need to pair anything. Just scan, find and connect. What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I have been trying the electronic-clinic example of receiving data from the Arduino and displaying it in an app. But they use a Bluetooth module that can be paired with. I am not very experience with android studio and do not know how to code a Bluetooth connection, I only have experience making an app that can detect Bluetooth. 

The tutorial I have been using is: https://www.electroniclinic.com/how-to-create-android-app-for-arduino-sensor-monitoring-over-bluetooth/

The Bluetooth connection code is located in the MainActivity.java code

Answer (score 1):

Did you found a solution? I think you need to be sure, that you are connect with Bluetooth Low Energy with the Nano Board from Arduino. The way, which is descripted in your posted Tutorial, is not Low Energy. Because of that, you cannot pair.

Answer (score 1):

To connect the Arduino nano 33 IoT via BLE you can use the Demo by Bernardo Giovanni as a template code for your project.

https://www.settorezero.com

```
*/

// Voltage divider definitions. 
// Here I've reported my precise values for R1 (47K) and R2 (33K)
// remember: you cannot apply more than 3.3V on analog input. 
// Having a voltage divider with those values (47K and 33K)
// consent to apply on the voltage divider input a maximum of:
// 3.3/VDK = 3.3/0.4125 = 8V
#define R1  46.2F
#define R2  32.86F
#define VDK  (R2/(R1+R2))

// since I'm using a 4xAA battery holder and you cannot apply
// less than 5V on Vin pin, I define my "battery full" value as 6V
// and "battery low" value as 5V
#define BAT_FUL 6
#define BAT_LOW 5

// analog pin connected to the voltage divider for battery 
// voltage reading
#define AN_BAT  A7

#include <ArduinoBLE.h> // Arduino BLE library
#include <Arduino_LSM6DS3.h> // Use Arduino library for the IMU on the Nano 33 IOT

// UUid for Service
const char* UUID_serv = "84582cd0-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
// UUids for accelerometer characteristics (I separated x, y and z values)
const char* UUID_ax   = "84582cd1-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
const char* UUID_ay   = "84582cd2-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
const char* UUID_az   = "84582cd3-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
// UUids for gyroscope characteristics (as above)
const char* UUID_gx   = "84582cd4-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
const char* UUID_gy   = "84582cd5-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
const char* UUID_gz   = "84582cd6-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
// UUid for battery values (bap=percent, ba=voltage)
const char* UUID_bap  = "84582cd7-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";
const char* UUID_ba   = "84582cd8-3df0-4e73-9496-29010d7445dd";

// BLE Service
BLEService myService(UUID_serv); 

// BLE Characteristics
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chAX(UUID_ax,  BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chAY(UUID_ay,  BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chAZ(UUID_az,  BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chGX(UUID_gx,  BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chGY(UUID_gy,  BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chGZ(UUID_gz,  BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic chBAP(UUID_bap, BLERead|BLENotify);
BLEFloatCharacteristic  chBA(UUID_ba,  BLERead|BLENotify);

void setup() 
  {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  uint32_t t=millis();
  while (!Serial) // wait 5 seconds for serial connection
    {
    if ((millis()-t) > 5000) break;
    }
  bool err=false;
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // onboard led
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // led off

  // init IMU
  if (!IMU.begin()) 
    {
    Serial.println("IMU: failed");
    err=true;
    }
  Serial.println("IMU: ok");

  // init BLE
  if (!BLE.begin()) 
    {
    Serial.println("BLE: failed");
    err=true;
    }
  Serial.println("BLE: ok");

  // error: flash led forever
  if (err)
    {
    Serial.println("Init error. System halted");
    while(1)
      {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // led on
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // led off
      delay(500);  
      } 
    }

  // BLE service
  // correct sequence:
  // set BLE name > advertised service > add characteristics > add service > set initial values > advertise

  // Set BLE name
  BLE.setLocalName("Settorezero_IMU");
  BLE.setDeviceName("Arduino"); // Arduino is the default value on this module
  
  // Set advertised Service
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(myService);
  
  // Add characteristics to the Service
  myService.addCharacteristic(chAX);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chAY);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chAZ);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chGX);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chGY);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chGZ);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chBAP);
  myService.addCharacteristic(chBA);
  
  // add service to BLE
  BLE.addService(myService);
  
  // characteristics initial values
  chAX.writeValue(0);
  chAY.writeValue(0);
  chAZ.writeValue(0);
  chGX.writeValue(0);
  chGY.writeValue(0);
  chGZ.writeValue(0);
  chBAP.writeValue(0);
  chBA.writeValue(0);
 
  // start advertising
  BLE.advertise();
  Serial.println("Advertising started");
  }

void loop() 
  {
  static long preMillis = 0;
  
  // listen for BLE centrals devices
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  // central device connected?
  if (central) 
    {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // turn on the onboard led
    Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    Serial.println(central.address()); // central device MAC address
    
    // while the central is still connected to peripheral:
    while (central.connected()) 
      {
      // additional placeholder for writing command from central
      // to this device. "myCharacteristic" is a characteristic initialized
      // in write mode (BLEwrite) with his own UUid
      /*
      if (myCharacteristic.written()) 
        {
        command = myCharacteristic.value(); // retrieve value sent from central
        Serial.print(F("commmand value:  "));
        Serial.println(command);
        }
      */
      
      long curMillis = millis();
      if (preMillis>curMillis) preMillis=0; // millis() rollover?
      if (curMillis - preMillis >= 10) // check values every 10mS
        {
        preMillis = curMillis;
        updateValues(); // call function for updating value to send to central
        }
      } // still here while central connected

    // central disconnected:
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.print(F("Disconnected from central: "));
    Serial.println(central.address());
    } // no central
}

void updateValues() 
  {
  uint8_t averages=10; // average on this values count (accelerometer and gyroscope)
  uint16_t b_averages=500; // average for battery
  
  // accelerometer averaged values/actual values
  static float ax=0;
  static float ay=0;
  static float az=0;
  float ax1, ay1, az1;
  
  // gyroscope averaged values/actual values
  static float gx=0;
  static float gy=0;
  static float gz=0;
  float gx1, gy1, gz1; 
  
  // battery averaged value/actual value
  static float anBa=0;
  float anBa1; 
 
  static uint8_t i_a=0; // accelerometer readings counter
  static uint8_t i_g=0; // gyroscope readings counter
  static uint16_t i_b=0; // battery readings counter
  
  // read accelerometer values if available
  if (IMU.accelerationAvailable()) 
    {
    i_a++;
    IMU.readAcceleration(ax1, ay1, az1);
    ax+=ax1;
    ay+=ay1;
    az+=az1;
    if (i_a==averages) // send average over BLE
      {
      ax/=averages;
      ay/=averages;
      az/=averages;
      //Serial.println("Accelerometer: "+String(ax)+","+String(ay)+","+String(az));
      chAX.writeValue(ax);
      chAY.writeValue(ay);
      chAZ.writeValue(az); 
      ax=0;
      ay=0;
      az=0;
      i_a=0;
      }
    }

  // read gyroscope values if available
  if (IMU.gyroscopeAvailable())
    {
    i_g++;
    IMU.readGyroscope(gx1, gy1, gz1);
    gx+=gx1;
    gy+=gy1;
    gz+=gz1;
    if (i_g==averages) // send average over BLE
      {
      gx/=averages;
      gy/=averages;
      gz/=averages;
      //Serial.println("Gyroscope: "+String(gx)+","+String(gy)+","+String(gz));
      chGX.writeValue(gx);
      chGY.writeValue(gy);
      chGZ.writeValue(gz);
      gx=0;
      gy=0;
      gz=0;
      i_g=0; 
      }
    }

  // read battery value
  anBa1=analogRead(AN_BAT);
  anBa+=anBa1;
  i_b++;
  if (i_b==b_averages)
    {
    anBa/=b_averages; // averaged analog value
    float voltage=anBa*(3.3/1023); // voltage on pin (if 3.3V => ADC gives 1023)
    voltage=voltage/VDK; // real voltage on the voltage divider input = battery voltage
    
    // send voltage in V to BLE
    chBA.writeValue(voltage);
    
    /*
    Serial.print("Battery: ");
    Serial.print(voltage,2);
    Serial.print("V (");
    */

    // calculate percentual battery
    // we must consider BAT_FUL=100% and BAT_LO=0%
    // report voltage to range having 0 as lower limit and (BAT_FUL-BAT_LO) as higher limit
    // for having percent value
    voltage-=BAT_LOW; 
    voltage/=(BAT_FUL-BAT_LOW); 
    anBa=voltage*100;
    // keep percent value in the range 0-100
    if (anBa<0) anBa=0;
    else if (anBa>100) anBa=100;

    // send % value to BLE
    chBAP.writeValue(anBa); // percent voltage
    
    /*
    Serial.print(anBa,1);
    Serial.println("%)");
    */
        
    i_b=0;
    anBa=0;
    }
}
```

There is also a good tutorial about BLE on the Arduino website

https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-33-iot/Bluetooth

and an excellent ultimate Android to BLE guide here:

https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/

other really useful guides, tutorials and OS code can be found on the links below:
https://github.com/nenovmy/arduino

https://www.thinker-talk.com/post/bluecard-part-6-controlling-the-arduino-nano-bluetooth-module-from-android-device